# Chat-API get messages encrypted in v3.2

Tags: php, encryption, decode, whatsapp

I am using Chat-API v3.2 and I am trying to receive whatsapp messages.
How can I receive messages on the best way? when I recieve them with:

```
$w->pollMessage();
```

It gives some messages encrypted:

```
rx  <message from="316**********@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="264A8F6D435E5A3E9A" offline="0" t="1457365604" notify="Hello">
rx    <enc v="2" type="pkmsg">33088cfcd5051221051ee62daa7e66ebe8459c328d7736fed71633d15d6a7374f48ce006358ceeca361a2105c36cb895c43536df0d48cad571da14a50a843a592bfa2bc43705f11e5443c05922f301330a210554b13d4c344c9da85819c9579d76f85bd546789fbbb4a2eca389414b9f06fa681009180022c001a6bbb88c07a1d4573b17701a2ef4462fdc328205057cf8fce09ccf13df33ce41bfb7d4472e2b7339571b0a4df956dc70f2815ca15e05febd639737b52e8dd3afd393b32ad569a326afa590c334d03b195b5f5705b003a400367833dc9c11e548e7e5e85af4cdea00574a59b58b92552b7bed9715022e91b6002372b93b2bc2feebe6924f2fdf572c47e6d88f3dbab036f7d63f1cc4b7e480b90c0dfe1433e594f245da633da810967f42b5963233a6ad6fa2a49ea60cd9af56743a9d5859e6141290091f2bccd46028ec233000</enc>
rx  </message>
```

How can I decode this message? or which function do I have to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can do the following:

```
$w->pollMessage();
$msgs = $w->getMessages();
foreach ($msgs as $m) {
    // process inbound messages
    print($m->NodeString("") . "\n");
}
```

Based on [this example](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/examples/Simple%20CLI%20client.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but still getting the encoded text. Tried the examples but no success :(. Is it whatsapp that is working against us by encoding everything?

Comment: a okay, thanks anyway to help. Hope encryption will be broke soon!